# Shouldn't first posts / late answers already offer the low quality post auto-comments?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, late-answers

If a first post or late answer is deemed bad, I feel flagging it as low quality is the correct step. But the post then ends up in the low quality posts queue, and only there the deletion-comment can be selection. Wouldn't it be better if one could select this comment already when flagging for low quality in order to simplify the reviewing process for the low-quality reviewers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would complicate Stack's software. You need far less reputation to review first posts and late answers than you need to cast low quality close votes. Making it possible in one place for higher reputation users would be nice, but is it really worth the effort? I like your idea, I just don't see it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about the different rep requirements for those queues. Nonetheless, it _might_ be helpful to those reviewers to see a more specific reason proposed by the flagger as to _why_ the post is low quality, and not having to manually type one of the standard-comments would (slightly, if we're honest) increase the chance that the OP would actually realize their mistake even before the low quality flag were reviewed.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I agree from UX point of view, but when I think about code complications and possibly needed refactoring, well, I guess you know how problematic it may be, especially right after huge closing system changes, when it might be not yet be fully debugged as is.

Comment: I see your point there, though the question whether actually implementing this is feasible is up to the SE team. If they actually notice this question...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler well, that's why I upvoted your question, right? Anyway, as an user I don't like bugs that follows changes, and as a developer I tend to expect them, especially when recent changes are fresh.